# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have our company websites and in that we have careers tab . All files of our company website are placed into  a root folder.So for different career openings we created different  pages which are being placed inside the root folder for e.g http:/mycompany.com/androidDeveloper.php.But now we want url to look differently i.e .When androidDeveloper.php is openned in Url I want it to be seen as http:/mycompany.com/Careers/androidDeveloper.php  but I don't want to create new directory as mycompany.com/careers in my root directory  is there any way where in above mentioned can be possible

I tried doing this in .htaccess file  but doesn't seems to work

Redirect http://mycompany.com/androidDeveloper.php http://mycompany.com/careers/androidDeveloper.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^careers(/.*)?$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: i used this i'm getting this error "The requested URL /careers/androidDeveloper.php was not found on this server." do i need to add careers directory and inside that all files i don't want to do this because we have many files for careers and we have to launch it fast and i have created careers subdirectory

Comment: Also tell me what is the actual URL you have on your link?

Comment: i'm trying on localhost first so shall  i give u directory structure how it is .. actually i don't know much in htaccess file this is what i added in my htaccess file RewriteRule ^careers(/.*)?$ androidDeveloperJobs.php$1 [L,NC]

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you just tell me what is the actual URL in your links and what is the internal URL it should be rewritten to.